# For loop to create pandas dataframes - varying dataframe names?

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe

I would like to create 3 dataframes as follows:

```
basket = [['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']]

for fruit in basket:
    fruit = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
```

However, after running this, running something like:

```
Apple
```

Gives the error

> **NameError:** name 'Apple is not defined

But 'fruit' as a dataframe does work.

How is it possible to have each dataframe produced take a variable as its name?

Comment: I would suggest a dict over variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
basket = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
for fruit in basket:
    vars()[fruit] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
```

However it would be better practice to perhaps assign to a dictionary e.g.:

```
var_dict={}
basket = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
for fruit in basket:
    var_dict[fruit] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful and something I wasn't aware of. How would you then call the dataframe from just the fruit name (i.e. Apple), as I see the only way this way is just via var_dict['Apple']?

Comment: the first solution I gave would let you call directly by name, but the dictionary solution wouldn't

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating variables use dict to store the dfs, its not a good practice to create variables on loop i.e

```
basket = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']

d_o_dfs = {x: pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3)) for x in basket}
```

Not recommended , but in case you want to store it in a variable then use globals i.e

```
for i in basket:
    globals()[i] = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,3))
```

Output : 
`Banana` And `d_o_dfs['Banana']`

```
        0         1         2
0  0.822190  0.115136  0.807569
1  0.698041  0.936516  0.438414
2  0.184000  0.772022  0.006315
3  0.684076  0.988414  0.991671
4  0.017289  0.560416  0.349688
5  0.379464  0.642631  0.373243
6  0.956938  0.485344  0.276470
7  0.910433  0.062117  0.670629
8  0.507549  0.393622  0.003585
9  0.878740  0.209498  0.498594
```